# Writing Certain Data Values to CSV from Nested Json Object

Tags: python

I am trying to get some customer data into a flat file from a nested JSON object called through an API.

I am not a developer and I am doing this as a pet project and because I like learning so please be easy on me and ELI5.

I have been able to get the desired output from a for statement and I can write the JSON to a CSV, but I cannot write the desired output to a CSV.

The code below outputs the desired format in the terminal with the print function which looks like this:

SubscriptionID | email | customerID | Payment Method | Customer Name

```py
import stripe
import json

stripe.api_key = "SomeKey"

cust_list = json.loads(str(stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)))

for item in cust_list['data']:

    try:
         print(item['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id'], "|", item['email'], "|", item['id'], "|",  item['sources']['data'][0]['object'], "|",  item['metadata']['Subaccount'])

    except:

        print(item['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id'], "|",  item['email'], "|",  item['id'],)
```

This is the structure of the JSON data sorry if it is TMI:

```
'"{
  ""data"": [
    {
      ""account_balance"": 0,
      ""address"": null,
      ""balance"": 0,
      ""created"": IIIIII,
      ""currency"": ""usd"",
      ""default_source"": ""IIIIIIIIIII"",
      ""delinquent"": false,
      ""description"": ""IIIIIII"",
      ""discount"": null,
      ""email"": ""IIIIIIII"",
      ""id"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
      ""invoice_prefix"": ""IIIIIIIIIIIIII"",
      ""invoice_settings"": {
        ""custom_fields"": null,
        ""default_payment_method"": null,
        ""footer"": null
      },
      ""livemode"": IIIIIIIII,
      ""metadata"": {},
      ""name"": ""Mutualink"",
      ""object"": ""customer"",
      ""phone"": null,
      ""preferred_locales"": [],
      ""shipping"": null,
      ""sources"": {
        ""data"": [
          {
            ""address_city"": null,
            ""address_country"": null,
            ""address_line1"": null,
            ""address_line1_check"": null,
            ""address_line2"": null,
            ""address_state"": null,
            ""address_zip"": null,
            ""address_zip_check"": null,
            ""brand"": ""IIIIIIIIIIII"",
            ""country"": ""IIIIIIII"",
            ""customer"": ""IIIIIIIIII"",
            ""cvc_check"": ""pass"",
            ""dynamic_last4"": null,
            ""exp_month"": IIIIIIII,
            ""exp_year"": IIIII,
            ""fingerprint"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""funding"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""id"": ""IIIIIIIIII"",
            ""last4"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""metadata"": {},
            ""name"": null,
            ""object"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""tokenization_method"": null
          }
        ],
        ""has_more"": IIIIIIIII,
        ""object"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
        ""total_count"": 1,
        ""url"": ""IIIIIIIIIIIIIII""
      },
      ""subscriptions"": {
        ""data"": [
          {
            ""application_fee_percent"": null,
            ""billing"": ""IIIIIIIIIIIII"",
            ""billing_cycle_anchor"": IIIIIIIIII,
            ""billing_thresholds"": null,
            ""cancel_at"": null,
            ""cancel_at_period_end"": IIIIIIIII,
            ""canceled_at"": null,
            ""collection_method"": ""IIIIIIIIII"",
            ""created"": IIIIIIIII,
            ""current_period_end"": IIIIIIIII,
            ""current_period_start"": IIIIIIIII,
            ""customer"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""days_until_due"": null,
            ""default_payment_method"": null,
            ""default_source"": null,
            ""default_tax_rates"": [],
            ""discount"": null,
            ""ended_at"": null,
            ""id"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""items"": {
              ""data"": [
                {
                  ""billing_thresholds"": IIIIIIIII,
                  ""created"": IIIIIIIII,
                  ""id"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                  ""metadata"": {},
                  ""object"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                  ""plan"": {
                    ""active"": true,
                    ""aggregate_usage"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""amount"": 1,
                    ""billing_scheme"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""created"": IIIIIIIII,
                    ""currency"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""id"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""interval"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""interval_count"": 1,
                    ""livemode"": true,
                    ""metadata"": {},
                    ""nickname"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""object"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""product"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                    ""tiers"": null,
                    ""tiers_mode"": null,
                    ""transform_usage"": null,
                    ""trial_period_days"": null,
                    ""usage_type"": ""IIIIIIIII""
                  },
                  ""subscription"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
                  ""tax_rates"": []
                }
              ],
              ""has_more"": false,
              ""object"": ""list"",
              ""total_count"": 1,
              ""url"": ""IIIIIIIII""
            },
            ""latest_invoice"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""livemode"": true,
            ""metadata"": {},
            ""object"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
            ""pending_setup_intent"": null,
            ""plan"": {
              ""active"": true,
              ""aggregate_usage"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
              ""amount"": 1,
              ""billing_scheme"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
              ""created"": IIIIIIIII,
              ""currency"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
              ""id"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
              ""interval"": ""month"",
              ""interval_count"": 1,
              ""livemode"": true,
              ""metadata"": {},
              ""nickname"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
              ""object"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
              ""product"": ""IIIIIIIII"",
              ""tiers"": null,
              ""tiers_mode"": null,
              ""transform_usage"": null,
              ""trial_period_days"": null,
              ""usage_type"": ""IIIIIIIII""
            },
            ""quantity"": 1,
            ""schedule"": null,
            ""start"": IIIIIIIII,
            ""start_date"": IIIIIIIII,
            ""status"": ""active"",
            ""tax_percent"": null,
            ""trial_end"": null,
            ""trial_start"": null
          }
        ],
        ""has_more"": false,
        ""object"": ""list"",
        ""total_count"": 1,
        ""url"": ""IIIIIIIII""
      },
      ""tax_exempt"": ""none"",
      ""tax_ids"": {},
      ""tax_info"": null,
      ""tax_info_verification"": null
    }
  ],
  ""has_more"": true,
  ""object"": ""list"",
  ""url"": ""IIIIIIIII""
}"
}
```

The code here itself outputs as I need it in the terminal, but I cannot find a way to take this and put it into a file. For now I just copy the output from the terminal into a csv sheet.

I am looking for guidance on what to do. i.e. Do A first by doing x,y,z, and then do B by doing e, f, g.

Again sorry if this isn't the proper thing to ask here. I have been trying to find a solution for a while and I have not been successful, so I figured I would share my particular case.

Comment: Have you tried piping the terminal output to a file? Something like
```python myProgram.py > MyTextOutput.csv``` from cmd?

Comment: Don't use a bare ``except:`` - catch specific errors such as ``except KeyError:``.

Comment: have you checked https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/working-csv-files

Comment: it is so easy to write a csv file in python.

Comment: give correct json format string. JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a file and write to it as you iterate through. Something like this:

```
import stripe
import json

stripe.api_key = "SomeKey"

cust_list = json.loads(str(stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)))
with open("csv.csv", "w") as f:
    for item in cust_list["data"]:
        try:
            f.write(
                item["subscriptions"]["data"][0]["id"]
                + " | "
                + item["email"]
                + " | "
                + item["id"]
                + "  | "
                + item["sources"]["data"][0]["object"]
                + " | "
                + item["metadata"]["Subaccount"]
            )

        except:

            f.write(
                item["subscriptions"]["data"][0]["id"]
                + " | "
                + item["email"]
                + " | "
                + item["id"]
            )
```

Note that I replaced the "|" with " | " for formatting and exchanged the tuple for a string. You can make it nicer by using fstrings or `.format` rather than `+`.

Comment: This almost gets me there! I need to figure out how to write each tuple to a new row. right now I get the data writing in A1 until a data point with a comma comes up then is moves to A2. I am going to try and find a delimiter parameter and set it to " | " and then see if writerow or wroterows works instead of write. Do you think that will work out?

Comment: @sregor_nevets just add a + "\n" at the end, for newline character, so `+ item["metadata"]["Subaccount"] + "\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the data, you can assign your required formatted string to a variable and write the contents of that variable to a file.

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

```py
import stripe
import json

stripe.api_key = "SomeKey"

cust_list = json.loads(str(stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)))

output = ""
for item in cust_list['data']:

    # Save the formatted string to output
    try:
        output = str(item['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id']) + " | " + str(item['email']) + " | " + str(item['id']) + " | " + str(item['sources']['data'][0]['object']) + " | " + str(item['metadata']['Subaccount'])
    except KeyError:
        output = str(item['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id']) + " | " + str(item['email']) + " | " + str(item['id'])
    except: 
        # Handle exception as you see fit

# Write output to the file
with open("out_file.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(output)
```

I would like to note that if you are writing to a CSV (comma-separated-values) file, it is preferred that you use the `,` delimiter rather than `|` in which case the following should suffice:

```py
# Save the formatted string to output
try:
    output = str(item['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id']) + "," + str(item['email']) + "," + str(item['id']) + "," + str(item['sources']['data'][0]['object']) + "," + str(item['metadata']['Subaccount'])
except KeyError:
    output = str(item['subscriptions']['data'][0]['id']) + "," + str(item['email']) + "," + str(item['id'])
except: 
    # Handle exception as you see fit
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Separating out the KeyError will help is distinguishing that the error  maybe from a different issue right? The reason for the | is because some of the data has commas in it, specifically customer names. Is there a better work around you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can store each of the items in a list and use a two dimensional array to represent each of these values. Each entry in the list will act as the row.

Using an example if you wanted a csv with two columns such as ‘Name’, ‘Age’ it would look like so..

[ [‘name’,’age’],  [‘anon’, 22], [‘jane’,59] ]

Then you use an import named csv to be able to write this to a file.